# Android Studio AVD image x86 API 24 (Google Play) Graphics option disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

In Android Studio AVD Manager, when I create a new AVD, I always select "Software" in the "Graphics" drop-down menu. I do so because AVD doesn't start (I have issues with my graphics card) when this selection is on "Automatic" or "Hardware".
The latest x86 images for API 24 and 26 contain the Play Store. Unfortunately, the AVD manager disables the Graphics drop-down menu when these images are loaded. The result is I cannot create a working AVD with these images. Is there any reason the "Software" option in the Emulated Performance section, is by default disabled for the new images containing Play Store?
 Any suggestions?
[image: Graphics selection disabled]
[image: API 24 AVD containing Play Store]

Comment: AFAIK, this is happening when graphic card driver is not up-to-date.

Comment: @Blackkara yes I know. Unfortunately there is no suitable driver for my windows version, only the generic one. And it doesn't work as it should be. But I cannot understand why including the Play Store makes the AVD work only with the hardware...